# Looping over JSON object returning undefined for some elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In my JSON object in `posts.php` I have two arrays, `posts` and `comments`. Here's an example (`posts` is just [...] for this example but `comments` has 2 example comments:

**posts.php**

```
{
    "posts": [{
        ...        
    }],
    "comments": [{
        "id": "1",
        "submitter": "",
        "time": "1433601171",
        "comment": "example comment",
        "score": "0",
        "postid": "1"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "submitter": "",
        "time": "1433601211",
        "comment": "another comment",
        "score": "0",
        "postid": "1"
    }]
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$.getJSON('posts.php',function(data){
    data.comments.forEach(function(comment){
      var id = comment.id;
      var submitter = comment.submitter;
      var time = comment.time;
      var comment = comment.comment;
      var score = comment.score;
      var postid = comment.postid;
```

For some reason when I `alert(score)` and `alert(postid)` they are `undefined`, yet all the other variables contain the correct information. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason javascript does not like the variable name "comment" in the function parameter, because you use it twice. 
If you rename the variable to `c` for example, it works.

```
data.comments.forEach(function(c){
      var id = c.id;
      var submitter = c.submitter;
      var time = c.time;
      var comment = c.comment;
      var score = c.score;
      var postid = c.postid;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You having the same variable name of comment

```
//original comment variable points to commnet.comment
var comment = comment.comment;
//comment get overwrite from the original commnet
//now comment points to comment.comment
var score = comment.score;
var postid = comment.postid;
```

This causes score and postid to be undefined, because now you are referring **score** as **comment.comment.score** which is undefined

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are using same variable named `comment` for different purposes.

```
var cmt = comment.comment;
```

Statements accessing `comment` as object after statement

```
var comment = comment.comment;
```

will throw error.

Change variable name comment inside loop, and it will be working.

[**DMEO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/mwjL9tux/)